# Array search and combine in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays. Is it possible to create output array and add keys/values from first to the second one? My arrays looks like:

The first:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 11
                [expire] => undefined
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 12
                [expire] => undefined
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 6
                [expire] => 8
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 10
                [expire] => 4
            )
    )
```

The second:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 6
                [realname] => to_es.gif
                [extension] => gif
                [filesize] => 57885
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 10
                [realname] => to_joomla_2_customer_view.gif
                [extension] => gif
                [filesize] => 77182
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 11
                [realname] => to_nl.gif
                [extension] => gif
                [filesize] => 10990
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 12
                [realname] => to_PL_1.gif
                [extension] => gif
                [filesize] => 52826
            )

    )
```

How I'm getting the output array:

```
 Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [realname] => to_es.gif
                    [extension] => gif
                    [filesize] => 57885
                    [expire] => 8
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [realname] => to_joomla_2_customer_view.gif
                    [extension] => gif
                    [filesize] => 77182
                    [expire] => 4
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 11
                    [realname] => to_nl.gif
                    [extension] => gif
                    [filesize] => 10990
                    [expire] => undefined
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 12
                    [realname] => to_PL_1.gif
                    [extension] => gif
                    [filesize] => 52826
                    [expire] => undefined
                )

        )
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with `foreach` here; have you tried something?

Comment: Does the order of your array elements play a role? In the first array the array with index [0] has an id of 11. In the second array the first array has and id of 6. So how do you want it to be merged? Do you want to just merge it by array indexes or by id?

Comment: Hello, yes should be merged by id. Not indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function my_array_merge($first,$second) {
    $new = array();
    foreach ($first as $f_item) {
        foreach ($second as $i => $s_item) {
            if ($f_item['id']===$s_item['id']) {
                $new[] = $f_item + $s_item;
                unset($second[$i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    usort($new, function($a,$b) {
        return $a['id'] - $b['id'];
    });
    return $new;
}
```

Example on Ideone: http://ideone.com/TQIIkH

Answer (score 1):

I'm supposing your first array as `$array1` and second as `$array2` you can loop within first array and then loop in second conmparing `id` and when found mix both array in a new one

```
$new_array = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($array1); $i++)
{
    foreach($array2 as $key => $data)
    {
        if($data['id'] == $array1[$i]['id'])
        {
            $new_array[] = array('id' => $array1[$i]['id'], 'realname' => $data['realname'], 'extension' => $data['extension'], 'filesize' => $data['filesize'], 'expire' => $array1[$i]['expire']);
        }
    }
}

var_dump($new_array);
```

this will output

```
array(4) {
[0]=>
array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["realname"]=>
    string(9) "to_nl.gif"
    ["extension"]=>
    string(3) "gif"
    ["filesize"]=>
    string(5) "10990"
    ["expire"]=>
    string(9) "undefined"
}
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["realname"]=>
    string(11) "to_PL_1.gif"
    ["extension"]=>
    string(3) "gif"
    ["filesize"]=>
    string(5) "52826"
    ["expire"]=>
    string(9) "undefined"
  }
  // and so on
```

[**live working code**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/lzVgZZ)